# Wine check if WINEPREFIX is active(desktop=a/desktop=b/etc.) using c++

Tags: c++, wine

I have a c++ program I'm writing that uses wine to run Diablo II using the system() function calling a wine command.

```
(system("wine explorer /desktop=a,800x600 ~/Diablo/Diablo.exe"))
```

I have if/else statements running that command (as a condition) with /desktop=a, desktop=b, etc. in order to have multiple Diablo windows running at the same time but my program is calling each one in order(all the way to desktop=g before exiting, so it's kind of annoying).

my question is: How can I test (I'm assuming with a wine argument) to see if desktop=a is active and if it's not run Diablo in it, but if it is then move on to test desktop=b?

edit: This is what I have so far(goes up to desktop=g)

```
    int main()
   {
      if (system("wine explorer /desktop=a,800x600 ~/Diablo/Diablo.exe"))
      {
  
      }
      else if (system("wine explorer /desktop=b,800x600 ~/Diablo/Diablo.exe"))
      {
  
      }
```

edit 2: After some more research I did find this (bash):

```
result=`ps -Al | grep Game.exe | wc -l` && echo $result
```

that should work for my problem but I can't figure out how to call it from c++ in a way that allows me to pipe the output from it to a variable (not without creating a file and reading from that which I'd like to try to avoid if possible).

Comment: Your post is missing [mcve]